# Are there any official plans to support Dart on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

Googling the web I haven't found anything that says something about whether Dart should eventually become supported by the Google App Engine hosting platform.

Google *is* saying that Dart should also be considered a language for developing the server part for a web application.

Does anyone know more about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now available for managed VMs (still beta)

See

- https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/appengine
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gcloud
- https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine_samples

for more details

Answer (score 25):

An issue has been opened on Google Code for App Engine. I suggest you to stars it.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6092